# your connection is not private NET::ERR_CERT_WEAK_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM

Tags: 14.04, networking, google-chrome, ssl

I installed chrome on my machine. i am using ubuntu 14.04 i can access website except google sites.. when tried to access google site i am getting this error,

[image]

how do i solve this? my ubuntu version is 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue is due to lack of certification in Chrome version 59.X in ubuntu 14.04

i solved it using,

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3-1d
```

simply install above package will fix this issue....